# Angular oidc-client page reload

Tags: angular, oidc-client

I'm using npm package `oidc-client` in an Angular 10 app with Identity Server 4.

What I'm finding is that when I reload a web page in the browser it always redirects to the home page and doens't remember the current angular route.

I've found that this is because when the page reloads the `UserManager` tries to refresh the user object, but this is done asynchronously and therefore the `AuthGuard` sees `null` for the `user` because it hasn't loaded yet.

Can this be fixed. How?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings(this.appSettingsService));
  private user: User | null;

  constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {
   // This should wait until the user has acually loaded. Doing async just makes everything break.
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  login() {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  async completeAuthentication() {
    this.user = await this.manager.signinRedirectCallback();
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // This needs to be made to wait until the user has loaded.
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }
```

It seems to be impossible to change `isAuthenticated(): boolean` to `isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean>` because it is needed in `AuthGuard` where `canActivate` must return `boolean` and not `Observable<boolean>`
and so it's necessary to get rid of the `Observable`.